# Scheduling a nightly build in Jenkins with multiple conditions

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket-server

I would like to trigger a Jenkins build when the following conditions are met:

- Time is 22:00 PM
- A commit has occurred since the last build

I have only been able to either run it nightly (whether there has been a commit or not) using the *Build periodically* trigger, or only after a commit using the *Poll SCM* trigger or just a webhook from Stash.

I've tried using both *Poll SCM* and *Build periodically* but it ends but never running.

Does anyone have a solution for this case?

I would like my nightly to run only if there's been development activity.

Comment: Not that this solves the problem but AFAIK there's no _22:00 PM_. It's either _22:00_ or _10:00 PM_. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Git Plugin, Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables):

> The git plugin sets several environment variables you can use in your scripts:
>
> - `GIT_COMMIT` - SHA of the current
> - ...
> - `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` - SHA of the previous built commit from the same branch

If these are the same, there was no change. Use them in the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to decide whether your nightly shall run or not.

Comment: Good idea.
This will work even though I delete the workspace before each run, correct? If I remember correctly .git folder is not deleted.